# В алгоритме шифрования ICE шифруется только первые 8 байт, а не весь текст

Tags: java, криптография

Нашел и разобрал алгоритм шифрования ICE, но почему-то шифруются только первые 8 бит, как сделать так, чтобы шифровался весь текст?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class IceKey {

    private int     size;
    private int     rounds;
    private int     keySchedule[][];

    private static int  spBox[][];
    private static boolean  spBoxInitialised = false;

    private static final int    sMod[][] = {
            {333, 313, 505, 369},
            {379, 375, 319, 391},
            {361, 445, 451, 397},
            {397, 425, 395, 505}};

    private static final int    sXor[][] = {
            {0x83, 0x85, 0x9b, 0xcd},
            {0xcc, 0xa7, 0xad, 0x41},
            {0x4b, 0x2e, 0xd4, 0x33},
            {0xea, 0xcb, 0x2e, 0x04}};

    private static final int    pBox[] = {
            0x00000001, 0x00000080, 0x00000400, 0x00002000,
            0x00080000, 0x00200000, 0x01000000, 0x40000000,
            0x00000008, 0x00000020, 0x00000100, 0x00004000,
            0x00010000, 0x00800000, 0x04000000, 0x20000000,
            0x00000004, 0x00000010, 0x00000200, 0x00008000,
            0x00020000, 0x00400000, 0x08000000, 0x10000000,
            0x00000002, 0x00000040, 0x00000800, 0x00001000,
            0x00040000, 0x00100000, 0x02000000, 0x80000000};

    private static final int    keyrot[] = {
            0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 0,
            1, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2};

    // 8-bit Galois Field multiplication of a by b, modulo m.
    // Just like arithmetic multiplication, except that
    // additions and subtractions are replaced by XOR.
    private int gf_mult (int a, int b, int m) {
        int     res = 0;

        while (b != 0) {
            if ((b & 1) != 0)
                res ^= a;

            a <<= 1;
            b >>>= 1;

            if (a >= 256)
                a ^= m;
        }

        return (res);
    }

    // 8-bit Galois Field exponentiation.
    // Raise the base to the power of 7, modulo m.
    private int gf_exp7 (int b, int m) {
        int x;

        if (b == 0)
            return (0);

        x = gf_mult (b, b, m);
        x = gf_mult (b, x, m);
        x = gf_mult (x, x, m);
        return (gf_mult (b, x, m));
    }

    // Carry out the ICE 32-bit permutation.
    private int perm32 (int x) {
        int     res = 0;
        int     i = 0;

        while (x != 0) {
            if ((x & 1) != 0)
                res |= pBox[i];
            i++;
            x >>>= 1;
        }

        return (res);
    }

    // Initialise the substitution/permutation boxes.
    private void    spBoxInit () {
        int     i;

        spBox = new int[4][1024];

        for (i=0; i<1024; i++) {
            int col = (i >>> 1) & 0xff;
            int row = (i & 0x1) | ((i & 0x200) >>> 8);
            int x;

            x = gf_exp7 (col ^ sXor[0][row], sMod[0][row]) << 24;
            spBox[0][i] = perm32 (x);

            x = gf_exp7 (col ^ sXor[1][row], sMod[1][row]) << 16;
            spBox[1][i] = perm32 (x);

            x = gf_exp7 (col ^ sXor[2][row], sMod[2][row]) << 8;
            spBox[2][i] = perm32 (x);

            x = gf_exp7 (col ^ sXor[3][row], sMod[3][row]);
            spBox[3][i] = perm32 (x);
        }
    }

    // Create a new ICE key with the specified level.
    IceKey (int level) {
        if (!spBoxInitialised) {
            spBoxInit ();
            spBoxInitialised = true;
        }

        if (level < 1) {
            size = 1;
            rounds = 8;
        } else {
            size = level;
            rounds = level * 16;
        }
        keySchedule = new int[rounds][3];
    }// если у нас уровень меньше 1, тогда будет 8 раундов, если 1 и больше, тогда раунды = level * 16

    // Set 8 rounds [n, n+7] of the key schedule of an ICE key.
    private void    scheduleBuild (int kb[], int n, int krot_idx) {
        int     i;

        for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
            int j;
            int kr = keyrot[krot_idx + i];
            int subkey[] = keySchedule[n + i];

            for (j=0; j<3; j++)
                keySchedule[n + i][j] = 0;

            for (j=0; j<15; j++) {
                int     k;
                int     curr_sk = j % 3;

                for (k=0; k<4; k++) {
                    int curr_kb = kb[(kr + k) & 3];
                    int bit = curr_kb & 1;

                    subkey[curr_sk] = (subkey[curr_sk] << 1) | bit;
                    kb[(kr + k) & 3] = (curr_kb >>> 1) | ((bit ^ 1) << 15);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the key schedule of an ICE key.
    public void set (byte key[]) {
        int     i;
        int     kb[] = new int[4];

        if (rounds == 8) {
            for (i=0; i<4; i++)
                kb[3 - i] = ((key[i*2] & 0xff) << 8)
                        | (key[i*2 + 1] & 0xff);

            scheduleBuild (kb, 0, 0);
            return;
        }

        for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
            int j;

            for (j=0; j<4; j++)
                kb[3 - j] = ((key[i*8 + j*2] & 0xff) << 8)
                        | (key[i*8 + j*2 + 1] & 0xff);

            scheduleBuild (kb, i*8, 0);
            scheduleBuild (kb, rounds - 8 - i*8, 8);
        }
    }

    // The single round ICE f function.
    private int roundFunc (int p, int subkey[]) {
        int     tl, tr;
        int     al, ar;

        tl = ((p >>> 16) & 0x3ff) | (((p >>> 14) | (p << 18)) & 0xffc00);
        tr = (p & 0x3ff) | ((p << 2) & 0xffc00);
        al = subkey[2] & (tl ^ tr);
        ar = al ^ tr;
        al ^= tl;

        al ^= subkey[0];
        ar ^= subkey[1];

        return (spBox[0][al >>> 10] | spBox[1][al & 0x3ff]
                | spBox[2][ar >>> 10] | spBox[3][ar & 0x3ff]);
    }

    // Encrypt a block of 8 bytes of data.
    public void encrypt (byte plaintext[], byte ciphertext[]) {
        int     i;
        int     l = 0, r = 0;

        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            l |= (plaintext[i] & 0xff) << (24 - i*8);
            r |= (plaintext[i + 4] & 0xff) << (24 - i*8);
        }

        for (i=0; i<rounds; i+=2) {
            l ^= roundFunc (r, keySchedule[i]);
            r ^= roundFunc (l, keySchedule[i + 1]);
        }

        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            ciphertext[3 - i] = (byte) (r & 0xff);
            ciphertext[7 - i] = (byte) (l & 0xff);

            r >>>= 8;
            l >>>= 8;
        }
    }

    // Decrypt a block of 8 bytes of data.
    public void decrypt (byte ciphertext[], byte plaintext[]) {
        int     i;
        int     l = 0, r = 0;

        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            l |= (ciphertext[i] & 0xff) << (24 - i*8);
            r |= (ciphertext[i + 4] & 0xff) << (24 - i*8);
        }

        for (i = rounds - 1; i > 0; i -= 2) {
            l ^= roundFunc (r, keySchedule[i]);
            r ^= roundFunc (l, keySchedule[i - 1]);
        }

        for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
            plaintext[3 - i] = (byte) (r & 0xff);
            plaintext[7 - i] = (byte) (l & 0xff);

            r >>>= 8;
            l >>>= 8;
        }

    }

    // Return the key size, in bytes.
    public int  keySize () {
        return (size * 8);
    }

    // Return the block size, in bytes.
    public int  blockSize () {
        return (8);
    }


    public static byte[] ReadByteArrayFromFile(String fileName) {
        byte[] buffer = null;
        try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileName)) {
            buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
            // считаем файл в буфер
            fin.read(buffer, 0, fin.available());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return buffer;
    }
    public static void WriteByteArrayToFile(byte[] buffer, String fileName) {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
            // перевод строки в байты
            fos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String s = "deadbeef01234567";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        byte[] key = s.getBytes();
        System.out.print(key);
        IceKey dokey = new IceKey(0);
        dokey.set(key);

        byte [] b = ReadByteArrayFromFile("plain.txt");
        byte [] a = b.clone();
        byte [] c = b.clone();
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Выберите пункт:\n"
                    + "1)Шифрование\n"
                    + "2)Дешифрование");
            int k = in.nextInt();
            switch(k){
                case 1:
                    dokey.encrypt(b,c);
                    WriteByteArrayToFile(c,"crypt.txt");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    dokey.decrypt(c, a);
                    WriteByteArrayToFile(a,"decrypt.txt");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ @ВладимирМартьянов

ICE это блочный шифр, с длиной блока 8*8=256 бит. Стандартный механизм шифрования блочным шифром обычно выглядит так:

1. Выравниваем исходный массив байтов, чтобы его размер был кратен размеру блока. Обычно последний блок добавляются байты, с тем, чтобы длина массива была кратна размеру блока, для чего применяется т.н. [padding](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F))
2. Далее выбирается [режим сцепления блоков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0) - обычно CBC
3. Если CBC то нужно чтобы как правило 1-й блок генерировался случайно - т.н. инициализирующий вектор - `IV`, для чего опять же выбирается [криптостойкий ГСЧ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)
4. Далее уже все более-менее понятно: берем блок, смешиваем по определенному алгоритму с предыдущим блоком/блоками - шифруем, складываем ну и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Не путайте биты и байты. А шифрует оно 8 байт, потому что так функция `encrypt` и должна работать:

> "Encrypt a block of 8 bytes of data."

в коде явно написано.

Для шифрования всех данных их нужно разбить на блоки по 8 байт и зашифровать каждый, например.

Comment: извиняюсь, ошибся. А вы не знаете, как можно поправить, чтобы шифровался весь текст ?

Comment: @Dima очевидно: разбить данные на блоки по 8 байт и зашифровать каждый.